# Add Stack Exchange badge on Facebook Timeline

Tags: feature-request, badges, facebook

Is there a way to create a Stack Exchange badge which, I can link it to my [Facebook timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Timeline) to show my Stack Exchange account details?

Comment: Try your [flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1129189/lexeroy/flair)? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I just want to add it on my Facebook account.

Comment: @animuson, how to use the flair in facebook?

Comment: I guess there'd have to be a dedicated Stack Overflow Facebook app to do this. Which as far as I know there isn't.